# Server removed/rejoined domain but not removed/rejoined farm

Tags: 2013, server-farm, windows-server, domain

I am facing a number of issues with one server in the farm - it had some hardware issues which meant it was removed/rejoined to the domain but not removed from the farm.

I'm seeing problems such as the STS not working, and/or services failing to start.

My thinking is that the SSIDs/SPNs that are created and (possibly) used by SharePoint for the original server domain account don't match the ones now being used by the server and its this that is causing me problems.

Can anyone confirm/deny my suspicions?