# People search blank until page refreshed

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, people-search

On a recent installation users have reported that when searching for someone the results page is initially blank when they click on "People" in Search Center to filter results by people rather than all items.  If they click refresh then the search works fine on refresh and continues to work until a new person is searched for.

Installation is a farm of 4 servers with only one server configured for indexing, two web front ends and an application server.

Steps to recreate

1. Enter search term "john smith"
2. Press enter to be directed to search results page
3. Search Center results displays all hits
4. Click on "people" under search term to filter the results
5. Page is blank but url is correct
6. press refresh / F5  - to display results

Browsers used: Chrome, IE10, IE9, IE8 - no errors logged to any of their consoles.

Comment: Works like a charm in my three environments. Strange!

Comment: Yep, never seen this issue either

Comment: What browsers are used? Any errors logged in console of said browser? Could be a JS-error

Comment: May be check the url. If there is any difference between the urls(i.e. before refresh and after refresh). May just give a pointer to the issue. :)

Comment: Check the uls log if a search query is issued at all before the reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was related to my other question [Server removed/rejoined domain but not removed/rejoined farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80845/server-removed-rejoined-domain-but-not-removed-rejoined-farm) as soon as we cleaned the farm of all references to the aforementioned server people search functioned properly.